# How to get the list of all the posts by a particular user in Express/Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User and Posts model, and there's a User's feed where all the posts submitted by the user will be shown.

**User.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
}, { timestamps: true })


userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (this.password) {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt)
    }
    next()
})

userSchema.methods.confirmPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)
}


const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

**Post.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var URLSlug = require("mongoose-slug-generator");

mongoose.plugin(URLSlug);

const postSchema = new Schema({
  postTitle: { type: String, required: true },
  postDescription: { type: String, required: true },
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  slug: { type: String, slug: "title" }
}, { timestamps: true }
)

postSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  this.slug = this.postTitle.split(" ").join("-");
  next();
});

const Post = mongoose.model("post", postSchema);

module.exports = post;
```

The routes look like this:

**posts.js**

```js
router.post("/new", auth.verifyToken, postsController.newposts)
router.get("/list", postsController.listpostss)
router.get("/:id", postsController.findposts)
router.put("/:id/edit", postsController.updateposts)
router.delete("/:id/delete", postsController.deleteposts)
```

**users.js**

```js
router.post("/register", usersController.registerUser)
router.post("/login", usersController.loginUser)
router.get("/me", auth.verifyToken, usersController.identifyUser)
router.get("/list", usersController.listUsers)
router.get("/:id", usersController.getUser)
router.put("/:id/edit", usersController.updateUser)
router.delete("/:id/delete", usersController.deleteUser)
```

So, I just want the posts submitted by the user to be shown on the Feed component of my react app.

Comment: Do you want to get only an array of user posts? Or users posts and user info?

Comment: Yes, users posts and user info. Can we do with mongoose's populate method?

Comment: Yes this is possible with virtual populate feature of mongoose, can you check the updated answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have any reference from user to post, you can use [virtual population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) for this:

First update the user schema like this: (note that I added `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` and defined `userSchema.virtual`)

```js
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);

userSchema.virtual("posts", {
  ref: "Post",
  foreignField: "userId",
  localField: "_id"
});
```

Now you can populate the posts from user like normal population:

```js
router.get("/user-posts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user.id; //change this to logged -in user id
    const result = await User.findById(userId).populate("posts");
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong, check logs");
  }
});
```

Let's say we have this existing user:

```
{
    "_id": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
    "username": "metalHeadDev",
    "email": "metal@head.dev",
    "password": "123123",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:18:22.948Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:18:22.948Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c"
}
```

And these 2 posts from this user:

```
{
    "_id": "5e3a88e2c511414a3c37a78d",
    "postTitle": "title1",
    "postDescription": "description1",
    "userId": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
    "slug": "title1",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:34.529Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:34.529Z",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": "5e3a88f1c511414a3c37a78e",
    "postTitle": "title2",
    "postDescription": "description2",
    "userId": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
    "slug": "title2",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:49.754Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:49.754Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
    "username": "metalHeadDev",
    "email": "metal@head.dev",
    "password": "123123",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:18:22.948Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:18:22.948Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": "5e3a88e2c511414a3c37a78d",
            "postTitle": "title1",
            "postDescription": "description1",
            "userId": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
            "slug": "title1",
            "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:34.529Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:34.529Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e3a88f1c511414a3c37a78e",
            "postTitle": "title2",
            "postDescription": "description2",
            "userId": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c",
            "slug": "title2",
            "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:49.754Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:20:49.754Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "id": "5e3a885ec511414a3c37a78c"
}
```

As a seconds alternative, we can use mongodb aggregation framework.
This solution doesn't require any changes in the schemas, and can be preferred.

```
const ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;

router.get("/user-posts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user.id; //change this to logged -in user id
    const result = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          _id: ObjectId(userId)
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "posts",        //must be collection name for posts
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "posts"
        }
      }
    ]);

    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.send(result[0]);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send("User not found");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong, check logs");
  }
});
```

This will give the same result.

Comment: I tried it via Postman, but it's saying server error occurred.

Comment: @metalHeadDev  you accepted this answer before trying? Did you made any changes to my code? I updated the answer with try catch and error logging. What display in the console logs?

Comment: Yeah. Thought it was gonna work lol. Can you show me how to do it with populate, and not virtual populate?

Comment: @metalHeadDev I tried this answer before posting, so it definetely works.  We can use only virtual populate here, because in your user schema there is no reference to post.

Comment: Try, catch, where?

Comment: @metalHeadDev now updated,  another option is mongodb aggregation, are you interested in that solution?

Comment: Okay, I'll try if this works. Yes open to any solution.

Comment: @metalHeadDev I added aggregation solution, and tested also.

Comment: One question, where is ```posts``` in ```populate("posts")``` coming from??

Comment: @metalHeadDev it comes from here in the schema: userSchema.virtual("posts",